# Handle deep exceptions, from inside onClickListener

Tags: java, android, exception, onclicklistener

I have a method that defines an `onClickListener` on some `Button`, 
this method throws exceptions.

```
  void foo() throws Exception{
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        buttonClicked();
                    }
                });
            }
```

and the method `buttonClicked()` also throws an exception!

```
  void buttonClicked() throws Exception{
        //some code that can cause exception
   }
```

---

What I want to do is to catch the `Exception` came from `buttonClicked()` and throw it from `foo()`.

So I should be able to catch `Exception` came from `buttonClicked()` in:

```
try
{
    foo();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // HERE
}
```

---

Any idea on how to do so - **without using Interfaces.**

Comment: void buttonClicked() {   //use try catch
        //some code that can cause exception
   }

Comment: Do you want to throw Exception from buttonClicked() and catch it from foo() or what? Why you try to throw it both from foo() and from buttonClicked()?

Comment: @Hetfieldan24 Yes this is exactly what i am trying to do, throw from `buttonClicked` then catch in `foo` the throw again from `foo`. why? because I want to I use method `foo` in other places that needs to know whether `foo`'s code succeeded or failed plus also need to know whether the `buttonClicked` 's code succeeded or failed!

Answer (score 0):

That's what you want?

```
void foo() throws Exception
{
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            try
            {
                buttonClicked();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    throw new Exception("message from buttonClicked(): " + e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (Exception newException)
                {
                    Log.e("CATCHED", newException.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So then when you call `foo()`:

```
try
{
    foo();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e("CATCHED", "message from foo(): " + e.getMessage());
}
```

So if `setOnClickListener()` in `foo()` was setted successfully, but then the `Exception` was caught in `foo()`, you will receive the message from `foo()` once and message from `buttonClicked()` after each click.

Comment: Are you sure that onClickListener() was setted successfully? Can you post entirely code, how you caused both exceptions?

Comment: I tried this before posting this. As i said:
If i add this: String sdf = null; sdf.getBytes(); after setOnClickListener() in foo() and add the same code in buttonClicked(), so i receive the message from foo() once and message from buttonClicked() after each click.

Comment: Yes, I certainly do not understand. You want to catch buttonClicked() Exception (which's thrown when you click on button) in foo() catch block - which triggers when you call foo(). They are triggered at different times, so I do not think it's possible with try-catch logic. It seems, you should use some listener/handler in foo()'s catch block for this.